# How to get Renditions System Path in Documentum DFC

Tags: documentum

I'm currently working on a project involving Documentum, and I'm looking for assistance on retrieving the system path of renditions in the Documentum repository. I need to programmatically obtain the system paths of renditions associated with specific documents.

I've explored the Documentum documentation, but I couldn't find a clear example or explanation regarding how to achieve this. If anyone has experience working with Documentum renditions or knows the API calls or methods to retrieve the system path, your guidance would be greatly appreciated.

tried to get system path for renditions in documentum but i couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using the API (you can find the api reference on the support page or on google)

getpath,c,<r_object_id>,,,

ie: getpath,c,09xxxxxxxxxxx,,pdf,

You can also do this manually:

Get storage_id from dmr_content (which is associated to a dm_location that has the base file path)
Get the data_ticket from the rendition dmr_content object (a negative number)
data_ticket + 2^32 = number -> convert number to hex, split in pairs

ie: number=0000802134 -> /00/00/80/21/34

Join that with base file path:

/opt/documentum/data//<filestore_name>//00/00/80/21/34.

Comment: Not quite the DFC way as requested, but I have done many extraction script this way. A good advise!

Comment: If you don't want to complicate, I think to remember that sysobject.getpathex2 accepts format/page_modifier so you can use that to get the file path

Answer (score 0):

As I remember the DFC, you should could try to get the content via the sysobject.getContent(…) where you can specify the rendition. Have a look at this method in the documentation.